# Invertible matrix product of non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

From a singular value decomposition I obtain $\mathbf{F}\in\mathbb{R}^{2m\times 2n}$ with $\mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{I}$ and $m\geq n$. I have to find a matrix $\mathbf{E}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that the product $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{F}^T\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{E} & \mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{E}\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2n\times2n}$ is invertible. In case $m=n$ a possible choice for matrix $\mathbf{E}$ is the identity matrix, but in the general case $m>n$ it is not clear for me how to choose $\mathbf{E}$. Is there a guarantee that it will always work out? Any idea or references on this topic are highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not always possible. E.g. when $F=\pmatrix{I_2\\ 0}\in\mathbb R^{4\times2}$, the matrix product $F^T\pmatrix{E&0\\ 0&E}=\pmatrix{E&0}$ is singular because it has some zero columns.